# htaccess redirects the domain, but not individual pages?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a website that has changed domains. I have 4 specific pages that need to be redirected to their new equivalents on the new domain. Other than that, I want the entire domain to redirect to the new one.

Here is my code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

# Redirect individual pages.
RewriteRule http://olddomain.net/subdirectory/subpage1/$ https://www.newdomain.com/newsub/newpage1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule http://olddomain.net/subdirectory/subpage2/$ https://www.newdomain.com/newsub/newpage2/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule http://olddomain.net/subdirectory/subpage3/$ https://www.newdomain.com/newsub/newpage3/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule http://olddomain.net/subdirectory/subpage4/$ https://www.newdomain.com/newsub/newpage4/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

I have also tried writing the RewriteRules like this, but it has the same effect:

```
RewriteRule ^/subdirectory/subpage1/$ https://www.newdomain.com/newsub/newpage1/ [R=301,L]
```

This only seems to perform the last line, that is, it always redirects to http://www.newdomain.com/, regardless of what olddomain.net URL was entered. How do I get the individual URLs to redirect?

SOLVED: Here is what I ended up using:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdirectory/subpage1/$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.newdomain.com/newsub/subpage1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdirectory/subpage2/$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.newdomain.com/newsub/subpage2/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdirectory/subpage3/$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.newdomain.com/newsub/subpage3/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdirectory/subpage4/$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.newdomain.com/newsub/subpage4/ [R=301,L]

Redirect 301 / http://www.newdomain.com/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the RewriteRule operates on Path not full Uri, the second method you  tried works fine, just remove the leading forward slash:

```
RewriteRule ^subdirectory/subpage1/?$ https://www.newdomain.com/newsub/newpage1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^subdirectory/subpage2/?$ https://www.newdomain.com/newsub/newpage2/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^subdirectory/subpage3/?$ https://www.newdomain.com/newsub/newpage3/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^subdirectory/subpage4/?$ https://www.newdomain.com/newsub/newpage4/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I ended up figuring out a different solution before your response though :P